# Get Short month from YYYYMM in Oracle

Tags: oracle, type-conversion, monthcalendar

How can I convert YYYYMM (stored as a number in oracle database) to MMM-YYYY

For e.g.
For 202001 - I want to convert into "Jan-2020".

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TO_CHAR` and `TO_DATE` as the following:

```
SQL> WITH YOUR_DATE ( DT ) AS ( -- your data
  2      SELECT 202001 FROM DUAL
  3  )
  4  -- your query
  5  SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(DT,'YYYYMM'), 'Mon-YYYY') AS RESULT FROM YOUR_DATE;

RESULT
--------
Jan-2020

SQL>
```

Cheers!!